# I want to get CSS code for Button from this CodePen pen

Tags: html, css

I want to get the CSS code for my website buttons from this CodePen contribution: `http://codepen.io/daviddarnes/pen/VLXxMa`

The HTML code on my website for the button is:

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
```

But in CodePen it is:

```
<button class="button  arrow">Read more</button>
```

I've tried it and changed the CSS code from .button & .arrow to .btn and it works but the arrow in the :after selector is not working.

I want the CSS code for the `button arrow` button.

Thanks in Advance!

---

### UPDATE

I've changed the code and forked a new CodePen code and using it right now on my website. The new fork is working fine on CodePen here: http://codepen.io/AhmedElgameel/pen/rjPywd

But it doesn't work properly on my website!!!
This is an example from my website: https://wp-me.com/best-wordpress-hosting/

Any Idea?!

Comment: Add the `.arrow`.

Comment: I will need to change the HTML code of more than 100 posts to do that! The problem is with the :after selector. I've renamed '.arrow' to '.btn' and it worked.

Comment: So you don't have a problem anymore?

Comment: You have all 100+ posts hardcoded? that seems strange! I would assume they're being generated by some code in a loop. you would just have to update that looping code. However, if just updating your css code did the trick, then no stress

Comment: I've changed the CSS code from .button & .arrow to .btn NOW on CodePen and it worked fine, the problem seems to be that I didn't add the last lines for the :hover transaction.

Comment: @haxxxton  please take a look at the question again, I've updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following codes to add the button to your blog / website easily.

**HTML Code:**

```
<a class="btn" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    position: relative;
    padding: .8em 1em;
    padding-right: 4em;
    background: #009ed8;
    border: none;
    color: #fff!important;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .2s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

.btn:before, .btn:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: inherit;
    padding-bottom: inherit;
    width: 2.2em;
    content: "\00a0";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    transition: .2s;
    transform-origin: 50% 60%;
}

.btn:before {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.btn:after {
    content: "\F054";
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #b90c01;
}
```